# When I play music, music run and image changes immediately, again when stop, image changes to another image in HTML. How can I do it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

```
<div>
  <img id="startOrStopImg1" class="audioimage" src="short images/cdd.png" alt="চালু করুন">
  <audio id="audio" src="short images/riya.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls>Your browser does not support the audio element
  </audio>

</div>
```

This just play and stop but cannot change image.

Comment: Well where are you stuck exactly? You need to handle the various events of the audio player using JavaScript, and in those events you can change the src of the image. You need to do some basic research and then try something, and then explain specifically what your issue is once you try some code.

Comment: You need to show us more code, where is the code the handles the image switching ?

Comment: No, I need it, I have not such code. so please send me a code so that I can switch between two images and also audio plays and stops while switching,